# PowerEdge R510 can't boot to 20.04 after install

Tags: server, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on a Dell PowerEdge R510 with a PERC 6/i.  There is one VD configured on the PERC and I can boot to an installer thumbdrive and walk through the installer with no issue; the diks VD is detected and auto-partitioned, etc.

There are no other OS installs on the system. It's configured to boot via UEFI.

When I remove the install media and reboot however, the system lands at a `grub>` prompt, with the "Minimal BASH-like line editing ..." across the top.  If I run an `ls` I get `(proc) (hd0) (cd0)`.  Running `ls (hd0)` returns `Device hd0: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 0KiB`, then back to prompt.

I realize I might be dying on something UEFI related, but am unable to get the installer to boot in BIOS mode.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
-pete

Comment: Marking this up because I have been going through the same issue with a Dell PowerEdge R710 on RAID 10 (Dell PERC 6i), the situation is exactly the one you described.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is stupidly simple.

The Dell PERC 6i and PERC 6iR RAID controllers can create VDs bigger than 2.2TB but do not handle the large VDs correctly after OS installation.
So, when your system is equiped with a PERC 6i(R) RAID controller, create a RAID volume with a total size smaller than 2.2TB.

When configuring a RAID 5 of 6 disks of 600GB, the VD size is 2.7TB. Installing OSs like Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Fedora or Red Hat Virtualisation Hypervisor runs fine.
But after reboot, the system lands at a grub> prompt.
This behaviour is the same for BIOS and UEFI systems.

After I created a RAID 5 with only 4 disks of 600GB (RAID size of 1.8TB) and installed any of the above OSs, the system booted normally.

Happy GNU/Linux,
Thierry